# regenerate the ID row in a MySQL Table with a Mysql's Script or PHP

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

i have a database fill with information of the users who use my webpage. The table as many MySql tables have the ID parameters who is autoincrement. The issue is that when somebody eliminate his account from the site, in the database remain a jump in the sequence that i dont want cuz i have a script who fail if find some jump in the ID.

Ex.

```
ID   Name  PASS
1    Jhon  1234
2    Max   2233
3    Jorge 2232
```

If Max get out and a new user go in, this is what will happend.

```
ID   Name  PASS
1    Jhon  1234
4    NewU  1133
3    Jorge 2232
```

So what is the best way to erase some body from the data base in order to avoid this isuue, or if is not a way, its posible to do a PHP or MySql script who eliminate all the contents in the ID row and regenerate it in order? Thanks A lot! sorry for my english

Comment: Fix your script to not fail if there's gaps.  The database doesn't care, it's more work to change the behavior in the database and more prone to error to use the approach you suggest.

Comment: Am I wrong here, or I thought mysql got the value of the last instered ID, increased it then added the next row.  I don't remember it going back and trying to fill in the last record.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html

 I don't think mysql acts like described above.  To the point, script needs fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think not the issue with AUTOINCREMENT, but rather your script.

**ALMOST NEVER** do you want to restructure autoincrement numbers in a database. That defeats the purpose.

*I would rather recomend you work on fixing your script.*

**This is all kinds of wrong**, but from [Reset a auto increment field?](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/208801)

> Since autoincrement fields are
>   typically used as keys linking to
>   other tables, renumbering existing
>   records is not done often. If you
>   REALLY want to renumber them all, copy
>   the records to a new table but leave
>   off the autoincrement field. TRUNCATE
>   the original table and copy back the
>   original records, supplying NULL for
>   the autoincrement field.

Using this approach, you will also have to manually update all foreign keys, links to these new IDs, **which seems like a very big taks compared to fixing your script**

Comment: I can't believe. Am I still on SO? Not a literal answer and even accepted. Previous id renumbering question got 7 answers, 6 of them were literal and direct.

Comment: Sorry, but not really sure what you are getting at? The fact that you are still sitting in fornt of SO?

Answer (score 1):

***It is not recommended that you try to keep your primary keys sequential.*** It is much better to rewrite your script to not have this dependency. Changing primary keys on your data is a bad idea for both data integrity and performance.

Comment: ok, but in one part of my page i have an script who give me ramdom lines of my data base, this script call the table asking for the max ID and the via PHP generate a ramdom number and then call the line with that ID, but as you see this method could fail if exist jumps in the ID. Can you help me with this? Thanks

Comment: @Domingo if your database relatively small, say, up to 10000 rows, you can get random row with `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to re-arrange the primary keys in a table. As you have the table is users table. It may be related to another tables by foreign key. There may be reference of user table's primary key in another table. In case you re-arrange primary key in the table you also have to manage all related tables also.
So try to fix the bugs in your script.